# Add loading to sweetalert when send request to livewire

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, sweetalert

I wrote my code below and it works correctly and the answer is received correctly. But the problem is that when the confirm button is clicked, the sweetalert closes

I want the sweetalert not to be closed until the request is fully executed and the loading button to be displayed. I saw a lot of questions about this but they were related to ajax and I could not create them for livewire

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    $('.eg-swal-av3').on("click", function (e) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'title',
            text: "content",
            icon: 'info',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'بله ایجاد کن',
            cancelButtonText : 'لغو',
        }).then(function (result) {
            if (result.value) {
                @this.call('createRequest');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`preConfirm`](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#preConfirm)  property, which accepts a callback. This is where you would run the call to your `createRequest`.

I would also add a `allowOutsideClick` to be true when loading, so that the alert is visible throughout the request.

```js
Swal.fire({
    title: 'title',
    text: "content",
    icon: 'info',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'بله ایجاد کن',
    cancelButtonText : 'لغو',
    allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
    preConfirm: function(result) {
        if (result) {
            return @this.call('createRequest').then(() => {
                Swal.fire('Loading complete');
            });
        }
    },
});
```